# Call but not download a page with wget

Tags: windows, download, wget, gnu, arguments

I was wondering if there was any argument that allowed me to use `wget` and "call" a page, but **without downloading the page**.

The problem is that when you call `wget` on a page, it downloads it to the folder `wget.exe` resides in, but I don't want to download a file every time I use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `--spider` option.

```
--spider

When invoked with this option, Wget will behave as a Web spider,
which means that it will not download the pages, just check that
they are there. You can use it to check your bookmarks, e.g. with:

            wget --spider --force-html -i bookmarks.html
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Beware that --spider may perform a HEAD request instead of a GET request, which means the URL may react differently.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Wget is a free software package for **retrieving files using HTTP, HTTPS and FTP**. If you are not actually interested in *retrieving* files, you may be better off using a tool like [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/), which may have more fine-tuned support for what you want to do. (Using the `--spider` switch in Wget, for example, is an experimental hack according to the documentation.)