# Shell script to get the response from server

Tags: shell-script

We are testing our server.

I am a beginner to shell scripting.

I need an bash shell script, to read a text file having URLs, query each URL to the server and check whether the application server returns a `200 OK` or `302 Redirect` response.

Can you point me to any tutorial or link to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
for name in `cat textfile`; do curl -s -o /dev/null --write-out %{http_code} $name  2>&1 ; echo -e "\n"; done
```

the explanation:

```
for url in `cat textfile`
```

Output all the entries in your text file with the `cat` command, and make the current pointer available through the `url` variable.

```
curl -s -o /dev/null --write-out %{http_code} $url 2>&1
```

Call cURL and suppress any progress status with `-s`, write any other output to `/dev/null` (it's a black hole which you can throw anything into) with the `-o` switch, then use `--write out %{http_code}` to give you the return code for each link you do, put the current link down with `$url`, and redirect STDERR to STDOUT with `2>&1` (in case you do get any errors). Then...

```
; echo -e "\n"
```

Echo on a new line, regardless if the last statement (that whole cURL block) failed.

```
`; done
```

Finish the loop.

This probably isn't what you wanted though, since it *only* prints out the return codes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wget` command [with --spider option](https://superuser.com/questions/9890/call-but-not-download-a-page-with-wget).
However this may cause HEAD request instead of GET which, depending on web site configuration may cause incorrect results. Another alternative is to use [curl](https://superuser.com/questions/272265/getting-curl-to-output-http-status-code).

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up to @qweet

Use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) with `-K, --config <config file>` command-line parameter. Each URL in this config-file must be defined with url parameter:

url="page/to/get"